# Simple php email validation

Tags: php, validation, email

Im making a simple "add your email to our subscription"-list. And i only want valid emails.

Im using a write-to-txt function.

This validation code seems to be working by only saying wether the input is valid or not. But it does not stop the code from writing the invalid emails to the txt. What am i doing wrong?

```
<form action= "" method="post" name="form">
<input type="text" name="email">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><br>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $file = fopen("emaillist.txt","a+");
    fwrite($file,$email . "\n");
   fclose($file); 
   print_r(error_get_last());

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  echo 'Thanks for subscribing';
} else {
  echo 'You have entered an invalid email - try again'; 
}

}

?>
```

Comment: You are doing the validation **after** you have added it to the text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only write to the text file when the validation has succeeded, like this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

            echo 'Du er nu tilmelds nyhedsbrevet';
            $file = fopen("emaillist.txt","a+");
            fwrite($file,$email . "\n");
            fclose($file); 
            // print_r(error_get_last());

        } else {

            echo 'Du har indtastet en ugyldig email'; 

        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: I've replaced my code with yours, now it doesnt add anything to the txt

Comment: You are entering a valid e-mail address in the email field right?

Comment: Actually, try now. It was checking the variable `$email` which was only defined inside the if statement since I just moved your code around. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Yep. Tried with both valid and invalid several times. 
It gives me this message all the time "Du har indtastet en ugyldig email".